# how to make a list of a lists of data frames into a list of data frames

Tags: r, list, plyr, rbind

I have a list of lists of data frames (or values I guess) that I need to be put into the list-list-dataframe   format to the list-dataframe format.  Please see the simple example below.

```
library(plyr)

my_function= function(df){
   means = mean(df$mpg)
   sds = sd(df$mpg)  
   # or
   #        means = mtcars *  rnorm(1)
    #       sds   = cars    * rnorm(1)
   output = list(MEAN = means, SD = sds)
   return(output) 
}

list_of_dfs=plyr::dlply(.data = mtcars, .variables ='cyl')
output = lapply(list_of_dfs, my_function)
```

Now I would like to aggregate it so all the `SD` values for CYL=4/6/8 are in one data frame and the `MEAN` values in a second data frame.

I've tried `do.call(rbind, output)` but I can't figure it out.

Yes, I am aware I could do some sort of group-by here, *however*, this is just an example.   You could think of each value in the list as actual data frames rather than calculated output.

Comment: Are you saying that, for every level of `cyl` in the data set, you would like to compute the mean and sd of `mpg`? If so, there are more efficient ways to do it. For instance, using _plyr_: `ddply(mtcars, .(cyl), summarize, mean = mean(mpg), sd = sd(mpg))`

Comment: Hey, so perhaps actually post valid R code so folks can actually help you.

Comment: I fixed it sorry guys.  Yes, I am aware that you can do some sort of group by, but this is just a basic example - these would actually be data frames, so if it helps you can think of the corresponding values being data frames like mtcars or iris.

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you want: it's a bit tricky because there are several levels of nesting.

First, a function to extract element `n` from each element of `output`:

```
tmpf <- function(n) sapply(output,function(x) x[[n]])
tmpf("MEAN")
##        4        6        8 
## 26.66364 19.74286 15.10000
```

Now apply that function to a list of elements:

```
v <- names(output[[1]])  ## "MEAN" "SD"
r <- setNames(lapply(v,tmpf),v)
## $MEAN
##        4        6        8 
## 26.66364 19.74286 15.10000 
## 
## $SD
##        4        6        8 
## 4.509828 1.453567 2.560048
```

If you really want data frames you could `lapply(r,as.data.frame)`

To handle your second, more complex case, you can extend `tmpf` as follows:

```
tmpf2 <- function(n) do.call(rbind,lapply(output,function(x) x[[n]]))
```

or

```
tmpf2 <- function(n) dplyr::bind_rows(lapply(output,function(x) x[[n]]))
```

(There's probably a pure-tidyverse way to do this with the `purrr` package.)

The second step stays the same:

```
r <- setNames(lapply(v,tmpf2),v)
```

Comment: sorry, i think this is really close to what i'm after but if I uncomment  #        means = mtcars *  rnorm(1)
    #       sds   = cars    * rnorm(1)  so that it is actual data frames I think I'm just missing something I can't figure out.       I would want to append (rbind style)  these corresponding data frames  so theres just two master tables   (MEAN, SD)  rather than 6 =3cyl values * (mean/sd)